# Mejorar método en Java

Tags: java, condiciones, else, metodología

He realizado un método en Java pero no acaba de mostrar lo que necesito. Cuando una ciudad es la misma en origen y destino debería mostrar el mensaje de error y no la distancia. Alguien me puede ayudar a modificarlo? Gracias

**Método**

```
public void anadirConexion(Ciudad origen, Ciudad destino, int distancia) {
    if (this.existeConexion(origen, destino)) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: No se puede anadir la conexion entre '" + origen + "' y '" + destino
                + "' :: Ya existe conexion entre ambas ciudades");

    } else if (!(this.grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes(origen) != null)) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: No se puede anadir la conexion entre '" + origen + "' y '" + destino
                + "' ::  La ciudad de origen '" + origen + "' no se encuentra en la red");

    } else if (!(this.grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes(destino) != null)) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Imposible insertar la carretera entre '" + origen + "' y '" + destino
                + "' :: La ciudad de destino '" + destino + "' no existe en el mapa");

    } else if (this.grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes(origen.equals(destino)) != null) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: No se puede anadir la conexion entre '" + origen + "' y '" + destino
                + "' :: La ciudad de origen y de destino es la misma");

    } {
        try {
            this.grafoCiudades.insertarArista(origen, destino, distancia);
            System.out.println("INFO: Se ha anadido una nueva conexion a la red: Las ciudades '" + origen
                    + " y " + destino + "' ahora estan conectadas y la distancia entre ambas es de " + distancia + " kilometros");

        }
        catch (OperacionIncorrecta operacionIncorrecta) {
            System.err.println("No se pudieron conectar estas ciudades");
        }
    }
}
```

**Salida esperada**

INFO: Se ha anadido la ciudad 'Getafe' a la red
INFO: Se ha anadido la ciudad 'Leganes' a la red

INFO: Se ha anadido una nueva conexion a la red:
Las ciudades 'Getafe' y 'Leganes' ahora estan conectadas y la distancia entre
ambas es de 10 kilometros

--- Grafo ---
Nodo: Leganes. Lista adyacencia: .
Nodo: Getafe. Lista adyacencia: (10,Leganes) .

ERROR: No se puede anadir la conexion entre 'Getafe' y 'Leganes' :: Ya existe
conexion entre ambas ciudades

ERROR: No se puede anadir la conexion entre 'Fuenlabrada' y 'Getafe' :: La
ciudad de origen 'Fuenlabrada' no se encuentra en la red

INFO: Se ha anadido la ciudad 'Fuenlabrada' a la red
INFO: Se ha anadido una nueva conexion a la red:
Las ciudades 'Fuenlabrada' y 'Getafe' ahora estan conectadas y la distancia
entre ambas es de 15 kilometros

ERROR: No se puede anadir la conexion entre 'Fuenlabrada' y 'Fuenlabrada' ::
La ciudad de origen y de destino es la misma

--- Grafo ---
Nodo: Leganes. Lista adyacencia: .
Nodo: Getafe. Lista adyacencia: (10,Leganes) .
Nodo: Fuenlabrada. Lista adyacencia: (15,Getafe) .

```
    public ListaEnlazada obtenerAdyacentes(Object elemento) {
    int indiceElemento = buscarIndice(elemento);

    // Si no existe el elemento se devuelve nulo.
    if (indiceElemento == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    /// Se añaden a la lista todos los elementos que no tengan un coste infinito, representado con el máximo valor entero.
    ListaEnlazada lista = new ListaEnlazada();

    for (int i = 0; i < numNodos; i++) {
        if (costes[indiceElemento][i] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            Arista arista = new Arista(costes[indiceElemento][i], nodos[i]);
            lista.insertar(arista);
        }
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Comment: puedes mostrar el método `grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes` ? ahí debe estar el problema

Comment: obtenerAdjacentes con un boolean como parámetro?  Me parece extraño.

Comment: @Duston donde has visto eso? `grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes` no recibe un boolean como parámetro.

Comment: Lucas, por favor agrega el código de `this.grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes(origen)` para que podamos ayudarte. Y también cambia las imágenes del output por texto.

Comment: Hola, ya he añadido el código y he cambiado las imágenes por texto

Comment: @AndresGardiol De acuerdo, pero origen.equals(destino) sí devuelve boolean y es usado como parámetro como así grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes(origen.equals(destino)) .  Si origen.equals() no devuelve Boolean, entonces sería aún peor.

Comment: Y que crees que sería más conveniente usar?

Comment: @Duston si, no habia notado esa sobrecarga del metodo obtenerAdyacentes(boolean). Hasta que OP no agregue el código de `obtenerAdyacentes`, no hay mucho que podamos hacer aquí

Comment: Y no les puedo enviar por privado al correo? es que hay mucho código y no me permite subirlo. Gracias

Comment: Si no te permite subir el código, intenta borrar parte del código de la pregunta que no sea relevante para tu problema. Y sube el código de la función `obtenerAdyacentes` o por lo menos la parte mas importante

Comment: Ahora he añadido el código de la función obtenerAdyacentes

Comment: Para ver si el origen y el destino son iguales lo estas complicando en esta linea: `} else if (this.grafoCiudades.obtenerAdyacentes(origen.equals(destino)) != null) {` lo unico que necesitarias es `} else if (origen.equals(destino)) {` Sino, le estas pasando un boolean a `obtenerAdyacentes`, que no te da error de sintaxis porque esa función acepta cualquier objeto, pero se entiende que ese método espera `Ciudad`es en vez de booleans.

Comment: Voy a modificarlo, mil gracias!